# Generate R scripts from R script [Scriptseption]

Tags: r

I am trying to make an R scripts generator. The problem is that the new files are presented as text files and not as R scripts. Is there any way to present them as R scripts?

Expected icon: [image]
Result icon: [image]

```
require("here", character.only = TRUE)

files.to.create <- c("main.R",
                     "functions.R",
                     "explore.R",
                     "initialize.R",
                     "load_data.R",
                     "build.R",
                     "analyze.R",
                     "build_ppt.R",
                     "prepare_markdown.R",
                     "markdown_report.Rmd")

try.to.make.files <- function(file.name, path){
  if( .Platform$OS.type == "unix" ) {
    new.file.name <- paste(path,"/", file.name, sep = "") 
  }
  else {
    new.file.name <- paste(path,"\\", file.name, sep = "") 
  }
  cat(new.file.name,"\n")
  unlink(new.file.name)
  success <- file.create(new.file.name)
  print(success)
  return (TRUE)
}

invisible( lapply( files.to.create,
                   try.to.make.files,
                   here("src")))
```

**UPDATE**
Well it seems that if the file is empty Ubuntu handles it as empty text file, forcing it to show the txt icon and not the R icon. Filling the file solves the problem.

Comment: R scripts are typically saved as text files, usually with an extension such as .R. What is happening in your case?

Comment: Side note: use file.path to avoid worrying about the os specific details

Comment: Are you using windows? I guess this is a question of default file viewer...

Comment: Interesting. What about to populate the files with some default code? The code does generate empty files.

Comment: Update: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55894933/how-to-use-r-code-to-generate-an-r-script-filled-with-specific-text