# How to use R code to generate an R script filled with specific text

Tags: r

I know that file.create() can generate an empty file, but my request is to generate an R script filled with specific text, such as

```
#' This is specific text 

#' So is this

foo <- function(x){
  bar(x)
}
```

How can I save this text in a way that it populates a file I generate via file.create() or through some other function?

Comment: Works the same as the linked question. Just exchange `.txt` for `.R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about R script files. They are simply text files and you can use `writeLines` to write them to a file:

```
script <- "
foo <- function(x){
  bar(x)
}
"
writeLines(script, "script.R")
```

Here is a simple case to test:

```
script <- "
print('hello world!')
"
writeLines(script, "script.R")
source("script.R")
#> [1] "hello world!"
```

Comment: Any workaround when doing this for longer 'scripts' that naturally have lots of quotation marks and curly braces, multiple separate function calls, etc?

Comment: You need to escape some of the characters then. You could use `readLines` to read an existing script and look what gets escaped. Usually I start reading in a base script, replace the parts which need replacement and write it back out. The other day I wrote a simple function for that using `{{newspaper}}` as a placeholder which gets replaced: https://github.com/JBGruber/paperboy/blob/f9d125011fc51396db685445b49ad963f52424dc/R/utils.R#L17-L19